# Knockout validation - Validation group not triggering for different error updates?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm trying to set up a validation group to display errors after a button's pressed.

**My issue is** I can't get the validation group to update correctly each time the validation error changes.

In my example, I can see the the .errors property of the field observable update correctly each time I leave the text box (intended). For the validation group, the documentation points to calling .showAllMessages() or evaluating the group itself.

I've created an example below. A summary of the behaviour I see:

- On load, the 'required' validation message shows (ok)
- Whenever the validation error changes on the field, validation group doesn't update (grrrr)
- Once the field becomes completely valid, the validation group will update (ok)
- Once the field becomes invalid after being valid, it will update with the first validation message, but go not update properly as above.

In the example, I've set up these validations on a single field:

- required
- minLength: 3
- maxLength: 10
- numeric

**The view:**

```
<label>Test number</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: myNumber"/>
    <div>myNumber error: <span data-bind="text: myNumber.errors"/></div>

<div>Validation group: 
    <ul data-bind="foreach: validationGroup"><li data-bind="text: $data"></li></ul>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn" data-bind="click: testValidate">Update validation group</button>
```

**The view model:**

```
var viewModel = {
        myNumber: ko.observable().extend({
                    maxLength: 10,
                    number: {
                        message: "Please ensure that myNumber contains only numeric characters"
                    },
                    required: {
                        message: "myNumber is required"
                    },
                    minLength: 3
                })
            };

viewModel.validationGroup = ko.validation.group([viewModel.myNumber]);

viewModel.testValidate = function () {
                            // Try both, to be sure...
                viewModel.validationGroup.showAllMessages();

                viewModel.validationGroup();
            };
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996449/knockout-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like it's a bug from the older version of Knockout (v1.0.1).

The last released version is v1.0.2 (from Sept 2012), and the working sample below is from the GitHub latest: (last modified Oct 2013)

Here's a JS Fiddle of the same code above, working as intended:
http://jsfiddle.net/overflew/JhWZq/1/

So the .showAllMessages() is all that's required to update the group:

```
viewModel.testValidate = function () {
    viewModel.validationGroup.showAllMessages();
};
```

Reason for winding up with the old version: [KO Validation via NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Knockout.Validation) (Microsoft .NET's package management tool) was last updated June 2013 w/v1.0.1, which is now 1 or 2 versions behind.

Answer (score 0):

I have had hit and miss with ko validation. It seems to work the best on simple pages with simple models. I have found I needed to add validation options like this:

```
var validationOptions = {
    decorateElement: true,
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: false,
    parseInputAttributes: true,
    messageTemplate: null,
    grouping: {
        deep: true
    },
};
```

and then when I apply the bindings I use

```
ko.applyBindingsWithValidation(self, $id, validationOptions);
```

Let me know if that works.